# Windows 10 Git Bash emulation not working

Tags: bash, windows-10, git-bash, mingw-w64

I need to install and use git bash for my class.

Specifically, I'm trying to install git version 2.37.3 from https://gitforwindows.org/

Every time I try install it and launch it, I am presented with this:

[Screenshot of my git bash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqNc3.jpg)

The terminal is completely white text and it outputs "bash: module: command not found" and
"bash: /usr/bin/banner: No such file or directory" at the top everytime I launch it.

My professor's one is color coded green, pink, yellow, etc and doesn't have that error. One difference I notice is at the top their one says "MINGW64" while my one says "/usr/bash/bin --login -i"

What can I do to get git to be installed and working properly?

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: So it's not Git that doesn't work, it's the Bash emulator. Don't use an emulator, install WSL and run an actual Linux distro. Check [Install Linux on Windows with WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) on the Windows docs

Comment: BTW that image is so low-resolution it's completely unreadable

Comment: Sorry I've tried adding the image again

Comment: Don't use bash emulation when you can use the real thing

Comment: As for the error itself, there's no `/usr/bin/banner` folder on Windows systems. This has nothing to do with the Bash emulation. On WSL on the other hand, you have a full Linux file system

Comment: Don't try adding images at all. Do not post images here. Copy the _text of your window_ into the text of your question _as text_, not as an image.

Comment: Anyhow -- `banner` is not part of git, so banner not being present does not mean anything is wrong with git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`What can I do to get bash to be installed and working properly?` don't use Bash emulation to begin with. Use the real thing. Windows 10 allows running an actual Linux distribution as a [Windows Sybsystem](Windows Subsystem for Linux). That's faster than a VM and definitely faster and more compatible than Bash emulation. WSL is running an actual Linux distribution, not just emulating the shell.

> The Windows Subsystem for Linux lets developers run a GNU/Linux environment -- including most command-line tools, utilities, and applications -- directly on Windows, unmodified, without the overhead of a traditional virtual machine or dualboot setup.

All you need to [start using Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) is execute :

```
wsl --install
```

By default this installs Ubuntu. You can specify a different distribution. It's also possible to install *multiple* distributions.

It's possible to [work with files across file systems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/filesystems) and use Windows Explorer to work with Linux files, or a Linux shell to work with Windows files.